# Fade between pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Whats the best way to fade between servel images? I can find a free user control the does it. So as i see it i have two choices

1) Try to incorporate some javascript, the java script is on this page http://slayeroffice.com/code/imageCrossFade/xfade2.html
But how can it be done

2) Can I somehow encapsulate the Javascript in a asp.net control, cause ill have to use the component more places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at jquery tools

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/combine/portfolio/index.html

Theres various demos to look at, maybe one will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [jquery cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for that sort of thing and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery

http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm